# how to initiate a variable in a UIImage(named: firstImage = array.sample()) in swift

Tags: iphone, swift

I just started with Swift programming. I'm trying to display a random image to the UIImageView randomly. sample() is my random function.
so I declare the variable as such:

```
var firstImage: String
```

then i use:

```
prototypeImage1.image = UIImage(named: firstImage = array.sample())
```

so I can use the variable firstImage in another method so I can display the picture clicked on to another spot. but it keeps giving me a compiler around saying that
"() is not convertible to String"

Edit:

```
func setImageForSpot(){ 
    prototypeImage1.image = UIImage(named: firstImage = array.sample()) 
    prototypeImage2.image = UIImage(named: secondImage = array.sample()) 
    prototypeImage3.image = UIImage(named: thirdImage = array.sample())
}
func chooseSpotToDisplayWhenClicked(spot:Int){
    switch spot {
        case 0: prototypeImage6.image = UIImage(named: firstImage)
        case 1: prototypeImage6.image = UIImage(named: secondImage)
        case 2: prototypeImage6.image = UIImage(named: thirdImage)
        default: prototypeImage6.image = nil 
    }
 }
```

Comment: func setImageForSpot(){
    prototypeImage1.image = UIImage(named: firstImage = array.sample())
    prototypeImage2.image = UIImage(named: secondImage = array.sample())
    prototypeImage3.image = UIImage(named: thirdImage = array.sample())
}
func chooseSpotToDisplayWhenClicked(spot:Int){
    switch spot
    {
     case 0:
         prototypeImage6.image = UIImage(named: firstImage)
     case 1:
         prototypeImage6.image = UIImage(named: secondImage)
     case 2:
         prototypeImage6.image = UIImage(named: thirdImage)
      default:
         prototypeImage6.image = nil
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a value to firstImage like this. Just break it down and it should work if your sample() function is working correctly. BTW Swift is a type-inferred language. Give it a try.

```
extension Array {
    var sample:T {
    return self[ Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))) ]
    }
}
let inputArray = ["named1", "named2"]
var firstImage = ""

firstImage = inputArray.sample // "named1"
prototypeImage1.image = UIImage(named: firstImage)
```

Comment: That is actually how I was doing it before, but it does not display the images randomly, since firstImage only gets the first image in the array. Example: the first image in my array is blue. it always display blue even if I click the restart button, which should generate another image from the array

Comment: I have created a function for you to randomly pick an element from your array.